# Attempt to fake a 2D multidimentional array in bash by storing the array name as string

Tags: bash, array

I am trying to create a structure that will allow me to group data inside an array in bash

Here is what I have tried:

```
indexes=()
first_element=( value='one' another_value='two' yet_another_value='three')
indexes+=('first_element')

second_element=( value='four' another_value='five' yet_another_value='six')
indexes+=('second_element')

for i in "${indexes[@]}"
do
    # Here the i variable contains the name of the array I am supposed to loop through
    # but I cannot fugure out how to access that array using the stored string...
    for j in "${j[@]}"
    do
        #Here I am supposed to get the actually array
        echo "$j"
    done
done
```

Of course it doesn't work... Am I doing something wrong, or is it impossible to access variables that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been answer on SO : [How to declare 2D array in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16487258/1195001)
when using bash keep in mind it's script and not compile langage like C or java, variable by reference or pointer are not used or at least not the same way

The SO answer suggests:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A matrix
num_rows=4
num_columns=5

for ((i=1;i<=num_rows;i++)) do
    for ((j=1;j<=num_columns;j++)) do
        matrix[$i,$j]=$RANDOM
    done
done

f1="%$((${#num_rows}+1))s"
f2=" %9s"

printf "$f1" ''
for ((i=1;i<=num_rows;i++)) do
    printf "$f2" $i
done
echo

for ((j=1;j<=num_columns;j++)) do
    printf "$f1" $j
    for ((i=1;i<=num_rows;i++)) do
        printf "$f2" ${matrix[$i,$j]}
    done
    echo
done
```

the above example creates a 4x5 matrix with random numbers and print it transposed, with the example result

```
          1         2         3         4
 1     18006     31193     16110     23297
 2     26229     19869      1140     19837
 3      8192      2181     25512      2318
 4      3269     25516     18701      7977
 5     31775     17358      4468     30345
```

The principle is: Creating one associative array where the index is an string like 3,4. The benefits:

it's possible to use for any-dimension arrays ;) like: 30,40,2 for 3 dimensional.
the syntax is close to "C" like arrays `${matrix[2,3]}`

Comment: Please don't post links as answers, especially when they are lnks to other SE sites. Just copy the relevant info over and ad it to your question. See [this meta post](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/1396/22222) for details on how we feel about that.

Comment: OK I get the point, though I really don't understand how work the wiki post ?

Comment: You don't need to mark it as community wiki. You _can_ if you feel bad about getting rep points from another's work, but if you just expand the answer or correct i a little you have added to it and deserve the rep. Anyway, if you _want_ to make it community wiki, there is a little check box on the bottom right of the answer text box when you click on "Edit".